# How does keyboard buffer words different with programs?

Tags: keyboard, buffer

When i try to find something about the keyboard buffer the answer is always the keyboard buffer is to store keystrokes before they are processed,but the there is something that bugging me because i don't understand,when a program is involved when the keystrokes supposed to be processed,for example if there is a command line or something else that holds text  and to process it you suppose to hit enter, 
How does the keyboard buffer holds the text before 'enter' for the specific program and doesn't interrupt with another program that stores in the keyboard buffer?.
Or i didn't understand it  entirely  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The physical keyboard itself has a buffer, but that is not the only buffer used. The computer hardware, the operating system, and the program (or framework) itself can all buffer input as well according to their own rules. The specifics vary by hardware and operating system, but generally the scenario you describe can indeed happen.

Comment: so  if there is a command line and there is a text in it and waiting for an 'enter' to be pressed in which buffer does it stay?,in a program buffer or a keyboard buffer?

Comment: It depends on the platform, but for example on a .NET console app running on Windows, if you call `Console.ReadLine()` while the app has focus it is going to receive the keyboard input and store it in an application level buffer. The only time it would stay at a lower level buffer is if the system is too busy to process the input in time. At this level 'buffering' is really just a semantic concept; the system is basically at rest, the input has been processed, transformed into a UTF-8 string and stored in memory waiting to be returned to your program when the enter key is detected.

Comment: *And generally speaking no modern system is going to leave the keyboard input in any low-level buffer. Way way back in the 80s some software worked this way, back when an application assumed full control over the system while it was running, but you'd never do this today.

Comment: what do you mean by 'return to your program'?,like you mean as a blocking command waiting for enter to save to a value and continue the rest of the code?

Comment: Well it is all part of your program in a sense, but by return I mean returning a string from the .NET Framework code to your application code. And yes, in this case it does block execution of the thread until a return key is detected--but this is one particular implementation. There is really nothing special about it in terms of the interface to the keyboard--the string has nothing to do directly with the hardware buffer, it has been translated from the input. Holding down the 'A' key for a long time for example may generate multiple instances of 'a'.

Comment: [continued] so basically if I understand what you're asking, the keyboard buffer you're working with in an application is not the "keyboard buffer" proper, but instead merely a utility for your convenience which reads the direct keyboard input and translates it into a string. It is possible for the keystrokes to get captured by another application if it has focus, but the specifics are very dependent on the hardware/OS/application.